# Firefox open window.open not working

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser

I create tag `<a href="http://s02.radio-tochka.com:4870/radio" class="player-link" target="_blank">Button</a>` and after add event listener `var button = document.querySelector('.player-link');

```
    button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        window.open(
            event.target.href,
            "mywin",
            "width=340, height=280, status=0, menubar=0, location=0, resizable=0, directories=0, toolbar=0, scrollbar=1"
        )
    })
```

`, but Firefox open new window and in address bar just`about:blank`. What can be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Found in the docs :

> remote URLs won't load immediately. When window.open() returns, the window always contains about:blank. The actual fetching of the URL is deferred and starts after the current script block finishes executing. The window creation and the loading of the referenced resource are done asynchronously.

Comment: Ok, thank you for this comment! But how i can solve this issue?

Comment: most likely your script didnt finish executing